# Run Open GL programs on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: opengl, sfml, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mesa

Can the Raspberry Pi run OpenGL programs?  Like GL 1.x programs, not OpenGL ES 2.x which I know it can run.

The reason I am asking, I have trouble having SFML 2 start on it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/210381/15489

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the [Mesa software rasterizer](http://www.mesa3d.org/) to get desktop OpenGL support.

It'll be slow though.  Really, *really* slow.

Comment: It was _really_ slow. But it started up anyway. :-)

Comment: Either install the swdriver only Debian package, or force swdriver with LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE environment varible. http://superuser.com/a/210381/15489

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has created a desktop OpenGL implementation for Raspberry Pi hardware, for any version of desktop OpenGL. There are software implementations, but that would be of limited use on PR's relatively meager CPU.

Comment: This just needs a Mali backend for the glX wrapper afaik to work: https://github.com/lunixbochs/glshim